# Solubility of metal Hydroxides in excess Sodium Hydroxide (excess NaOH)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

I recently came across a question which asked me to find out which metal hydroxides are soluble in excess $\ce{NaOH}$ solution.

Number of hydroxides which are soluble in excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ among the following given hydroxide?
$\ce{Al(OH)3, Zn(OH)2, Cr(OH)3, Pb(OH)2, Mn(OH)2, Fe(OH)3, Ni(OH)2, Sn(OH)2.}$

Is there any way to determine rationally which of these hydroxides will be soluble or should I rely on remembering them?

Comment: The only hydroxides which are insoluble in an excès of $\ce{NaOH}$ are $\ce{Mn(OH)2, Fe(OH)3, Ni(OH)2}$. The other hydroxydes are soluble in a concentrated solution of $\ce{NaOH}$. I don't know whether there is a way of predicting this result, apart from experiment.

Comment: At least $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is soluble. Look [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76446/61578) for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three kind of oxides/hydroxides: basic (e.g., $\ce{NaOH}$, metal hydroxides), acidic (e.g., $\ce{CO2}$, non-metal oxides), and amphoteric (e.g., $\ce{Al(OH)3}$, Group 13 and 14 hydroxides). Amphoteric Hydroxides act either as Bronsted-Lowry bases (accepting protons) or as Lewis acids (accepting an electron pair), depending on reaction conditions. For example, $\ce{Al^3+}$ in $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is a Lewis acid, which can accept an electron pair from either Lewis or Bronsted-Lowry base:

$$\ce{Al(OH)3 (aq) + OH- (aq) -> Al(OH)4- (aq)}$$

The resulting neutral compound, $\ce{Na[Al(OH)4]}$ is much more soluble in water (it is a sodium salt) than Aluminum Hydroxide. Besides $\ce{Al(OH)3, Pb(OH)2}$ and $\ce{Sn(OH)2}$ are also dissolved in excess $\ce{NaOH}$ (Group 14 hydroxides):

$$\ce{Pb(OH)2 (aq) + 2OH- (aq) -> Pb(OH)4^2- (aq)}$$
$$\ce{Sn(OH)2 (aq) + 2OH- (aq) -> Sn(OH)4^2- (aq)}$$

$\ce{Zn^2+}$ in $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$ is also a strong Lewis acid, thus, $\ce{Zn^2+}$ can accept an electron pair from either Lewis or Bronsted-Lowry base ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_hydroxide#:%7E:text=Zinc%20hydroxide%20will%20dissolve%20because,charge%20and%20make%20it%20soluble)):

$$\ce{Zn(OH)2 (aq) + 2OH- (aq) -> Zn(OH)4^2- (aq)}$$

It is well known that $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ is also an amphoteric hydroxide ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium(III)_hydroxide) and Ref.1 & 2), which dissolve in excess $\ce{NaOH}$:

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3 (aq) + OH- (aq) -> CrO2- (aq) + 2 H2O}$$

Ref.1 also reports that following reaction with even water is evident:

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3 (s) + H2O <=> Cr(OH)4- (aq) + 2 H+ (aq)}$$

These facts leaves only $\ce{Fe(OH)3, Ni(OH)2},$ and $\ce{Mn(OH)2}$ are the hydroxides, which are not soluble in excess of $\ce{NaOH}$.

**References:**

1. Dhanpat Rai, Bruce M. Sass, Dean A. Moore, "Chromium(III) hydrolysis constants and solubility of chromium(III) hydroxide," *Inorg. Chem.* **1987**, *26(3)*, 345–349 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ic00250a002).
2. Richard A. Reinhardt, “The interaction of chromium(III) ion with hydroxide ion. An experiment for the undergraduate inorganic laboratory,” *J. Chem. Educ.* **1966**, *43(7)*, 382-383 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ed043p382).